# Loop through while loop and add up figures

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I'm getting figures from the database and performing calculations based on the billing_type and date. I am able to loop through and perform the calculations for each date correctly. However, I am now trying to add up the results of the calculations.

For example, if the results of the calculations equal:
10,
7,
30,
28

I want to be able to add them up and display the result of 75

Here's my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT billing_amount, billed_by, open, SUM(tickets), COUNT(casekey)
        FROM pcnclientreport
        WHERE open = '$date' GROUP BY '$date'";

$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res) ){
    if($row['billed_by'] == 'Month'){ 
        $gsliability = $row['billing_amount'];
    }
    else if ($row['billed_by'] == 'Case'){
        $gsliability = ($row['billing_amount'] * $row['COUNT(casekey)']);
    }
    else if ($row['billed_by'] == 'Ticket'){
        $gsliability = ($row['billing_amount'] * $row['SUM(tickets)']);
    }
}

echo $gsliability
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT billing_amount, billed_by, open, SUM(tickets), COUNT(casekey)
    FROM pcnclientreport
    WHERE open = '$date' GROUP BY '$date'";

$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$sum = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res) ){

    $gsliability = 0;

    if($row['billed_by'] == 'Month'){ 
        $gsliability = $row['billing_amount'];
    }
    else if ($row['billed_by'] == 'Case'){
        $gsliability = ($row['billing_amount'] * $row['COUNT(casekey)']);
    }
    else if ($row['billed_by'] == 'Ticket'){
        $gsliability = ($row['billing_amount'] * $row['SUM(tickets)']);
    }

    $sum += $gsliability;
}

echo $sum;
```

Comment: This is correct in concept, but will likely raise an undefined variable notice for $gsliability in the case that none of the conditions are met.

Comment: @KevinStich you are right. Even more, if it's not set in 2nd iteration it will add value from previous one. Edited code to just setting it to 0 with every loop.